# Dash board, centre console, radio controls and fuel, temperature gauges

Tags: dashboard, holden, commodore

Holden Commodore VE Omega 2013 Sport wagon
Dash board, centre console light not working. Fuel, temperature gauges not working
This just happened after the battery was disconnected to replace the Torque Converter which was leaking transmission oil. 
Why could this happened? 
What would be the fault?
How can this be fix?
Please I need answers
Many Thanks

Comment: Check the fuses, check the wiring under the dash and around the gear selector.